# How efficiently sort a list by groups?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, sorting, grouping

I need to group a given sort list by some given "blocks" or "groups" of elements. For example:

Given a list:

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]
```

And groups

```
[A, C, D]
[F, E]
[J, H, I]
```

the result should be

```
[A, C, D, B, F, E, G, J, H, I]
```

The blocks of elements can not be mixed with non-group elements. The blocks should have the same order. The other elements of the list should mantain their order.

---

I have already found a solution. But it's not the most efficient code as you will see.

I'm using java 6 also...

```
public static List<CategoryProduct> sortProductsByBlocks(List<CategoryProduct> products, CategoryBlocks categoryBlocks) {
    if (!validateCategoryBlocks(categoryBlocks)) {
        return products;
    }
    Map<String, BlockView> mapProductByBlock = mapBlocksByPartnumber(categoryBlocks);
    Map<String, BlockView> mapFirstProductByBlock = mapFirstProductByBlock(categoryBlocks);
    Map<Integer, Block> blocksById = blocksById(categoryBlocks);
    List<CategoryProduct> sortedProduct = Lists.newArrayList();
    Map<String, CategoryProduct> productsMapByPartNumber = ProductHelper.getProductsMapByPartNumber(products);
    List<CategoryProduct> processedProducts = Lists.newArrayList();
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
        CategoryProduct product = products.get(i);
        if (blocksById.isEmpty() && !processedProducts.contains(product)) {
            sortedProduct.add(j++, product);
            processedProducts.add(product);
        }
        if (!processedProducts.contains(product) && (mapFirstProductByBlock.get(product.getPartNumber()) != null
                || mapProductByBlock.get(product.getPartNumber()) == null)) {
            BlockView blockView = mapProductByBlock.get(product.getPartNumber());
            if (blockView != null) {
                Block block = blocksById.get(blockView.getBlockId());
                if (block == null) {
                    sortedProduct.add(j++, product);
                    continue;
                }
                for (BlockProduct blockProduct : block.getProducts()) {
                    CategoryProduct categoryProduct = productsMapByPartNumber.get(blockProduct.getPartnumber());
                    sortedProduct.add(j++, categoryProduct);
                    processedProducts.add(categoryProduct);
                }
                blocksById.remove(blockView.getBlockId());
            } else {
                sortedProduct.add(j++, product);
                processedProducts.add(product);
            }
        }
    }

    return sortedProduct;
}
```

---

Any advice to improve and make it faster will be welcome.

(edit with the improved code)

```
public static List<CategoryProduct> sortProductsByBlocks2(List<CategoryProduct> products,
        CategoryBlocks categoryBlocks) {
    if (!validateCategoryBlocks(categoryBlocks)) {
        return products;
    }

    Map<String, Integer> blocksIdByFirstPartnumber = Maps.newHashMap();
    List<String> partnumbersInBlocks = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (int k = 0; k < categoryBlocks.getBlocks().size(); k++) {
        Block block = categoryBlocks.getBlocks().get(k);
        if (block != null && block.getProducts() != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < block.getProducts().size(); i++) {
                BlockProduct blockProduct = block.getProducts().get(i);
                if (i == 0) {
                    blocksIdByFirstPartnumber.put(blockProduct.getPartnumber(), k);
                } else {
                    partnumbersInBlocks.add(blockProduct.getPartnumber());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    CategoryProduct[] result = new CategoryProduct[products.size()];
    Map<String, Integer> productsIndex = Maps.newHashMap();
    Map<String, CategoryProduct> categoryProductByPartnumber = Maps.newHashMap();
    int indexResult = 0;
    for (CategoryProduct categoryProduct : products) {
        String partNumber = categoryProduct.getPartNumber();
        if (!partnumbersInBlocks.contains(partNumber)) {
            if (blocksIdByFirstPartnumber.get(partNumber) != null) {
                Block categoryProductBlock = categoryBlocks.getBlocks()
                        .get(blocksIdByFirstPartnumber.get(partNumber));
                result[indexResult] = categoryProduct;
                indexResult++;
                for (int i = 1; i < categoryProductBlock.getProducts().size(); i++) {
                    BlockProduct blockProduct = categoryProductBlock.getProducts().get(i);
                    if (categoryProductByPartnumber.get(blockProduct.getPartnumber()) != null) {
                        result[indexResult] = categoryProductByPartnumber.get(blockProduct.getPartnumber());
                    } else {
                        productsIndex.put(blockProduct.getPartnumber(), indexResult);
                        result[indexResult] = null;
                    }
                    indexResult++;
                }
            } else {
                result[indexResult] = categoryProduct;
                indexResult++;
            }
        } else {
            if (productsIndex.get(partNumber) != null) {
                result[productsIndex.get(partNumber)] = categoryProduct;
            } else {
                categoryProductByPartnumber.put(partNumber, categoryProduct);
            }
        }
    }
    return Lists.newArrayList(Arrays.asList(result));
}
```

Performance:

Elements        New algorithm        Old algorithm

1200                0.002s               0.129s

12000               0.021s               14.673s

Comment: Is the initial list always sorted in the form of `[A, B, C,...]` ?

Comment: No, it's not. It can have any order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form the code you submitted, I cannot figure out how your algorithm is fully working.

I can write another algorithm that will do the task.

1. Mark the first element for each group

   ```
   [A,C,D] -> A
   ```
2. Remove from `list(to_be_sorted)` all elements from groups that are not marked

   ```
   [A,C,D] -> remove [C,D]
   ```
3. perform sort on list

   ```
   result ([A,B,F,G,J])
   ```
4. place removed element based on Mark

   ```
   Initial Sorted List [A,B,F,G,J]
   A->add [C,D]
   List is [A,C,D,B,F,G,J]
   B->as it is
   F->add [E]
   List is [A,C,D,B,F,E,G,J]
   G->as it is
   J->add [H,I]
   Final Sorted List [A,C,D,B,F,E,G,J,H,I]
   ```

Time complexity is the same as sorting algorithm

Comment: I used your algorithm and is easy and efficient. For 1200 elements it takes 0.002s and for 12000 elements 0.021s. Using my previous algorith the time for 1200 was 0.129s and and for 12000 elements some impresive 14.673s!!  thank you! I edited my question with the new code

Answer (score 0):

By your definition it isn't entirely clear what the conditions are to merge the results from your given list and 'groups' ( arrays ). However, here is a solution based on your requirements using the assertion

> *"You want the first element of the list not contained in any of the groups inserted between the groups... "*

```
public class MergeArrays {

    private static final List<String> FIRST = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"));
    private static final List<String> SECOND = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "C", "D"));
    private static final List<String> THIRD = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("F", "E"));
    private static final List<String> FOURTH = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("J", "H", "I"));

    public static List<String> merge(List<String> source, List<String>... lists) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<String> list : lists) {
            for (String value : list) {
                source.remove(value);
            }
        }

        for (List<String> list : lists) {
            String value = null;
            if (source.size() > 0) {
                value = source.get(0);
                source.remove(0);
            }
            result.addAll(merge(value, list));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static List<String> merge(String value, List<String> list) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
        if (value != null) {
            result.add(value);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> result = merge(FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

//Results

```
[A, C, D, B, F, E, G, J, H, I]
```